# SMTChecker error with CHC

Tags: solidity, smtchecker

I am trying to run the SMTChecker on a contract. When I run it with the BMC checker, it runs fine, although it's pretty hard to figure out how the checker landed on a given state.

I hence wanted to use the CHC engine which, according to documentation, provides the sequence of calls that caused a given erroneous state.

But I am getting many of this type error:

```
Warning: CHC: Error trying to invoke SMT solver.
   --> contracts/Voting/Voting.sol:188:9:
    |
188 |         assert(newDelegate == getDelegate(newDelegate));
    |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

There is one per each assertion (I am targeting only assertions for now).

The command I am running is:

```
solc-macos --model-checker-targets assert --model-checker-engine chc @openzeppelin/=$(pwd)/node_modules/@openzeppelin/ --model-checker-contracts "contracts/Voting/Voting.sol:Voting" --model-checker-solvers all --model-checker-timeout 0 contracts/Voting/Voting.sol
```

If I set the timeout to anything different than 0, but smaller than 1000, I don't get this error, but only a Warning informing that the properties could not be proved:

```
Warning: CHC: 5 verification condition(s) could not be proved. Enable the model checker option "show unproved" to see all of them. Consider choosing a specific contract to be verified in order to reduce the solving problems. Consider increasing the timeout per query.
```

Can someone give me a hint on how to debug this?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this happens when the underlying SMT/Horn solver issues an error via the query API. If you open an issue at https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/issues/ with the compiler/solver version I can take a look with you.